# Radio buttons don't align properly in a menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav-bar with a menu with radio buttons as menu elements, but they don't aligh well:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">

  <ul class="nav pull-right">

  <li>
 <form method="get" action="search" class="navbar-form pull-right">
  <input type="text" name="q" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Search">
    </li>      
     <li id="nav_search_filter" class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>Search:</li>
              <li>
                <input type="radio" id="search_filter_all" name ="search_filter" value="all" checked="checked"/> 
                <label for="search_filter_all">All</label>
              </li>
              <li><input type="radio" id="search_filter_inactive" name ="search_filter" value="inactive" /> <label for="search_filter_inactive">Inactive</label></li>

              <li><input type="radio" id="search_filter_active" name ="search_filter" value="active" /> <label for="search_filter_active">Active</label></li>

            </ul>
          </li>
</form>          


</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2SmWq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
label {margin:10px;}
input[type="radio"] {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
```

and wrapping the labels around the input tags in the html.

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SmWq/1/) to see what I mean.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I wander why it isn't included in twitter bootstrap

Comment: Well, bootstrap has the buttons that act like radios, right? You could use those and a jquery line to do what you want ... here I added a jsfiddle with that solution: http://jsfiddle.net/2SmWq/2/

Answer (score 0):

If what you want it do have the radio button and the label in the same line. Try this:

```
<style>

    label {
        display:inline-block;

    }
</style>
```

Comment: That solves vertical align only. But they are still positioned on the left

Comment: Change the radio botton to the left them.